# GitLab CI Job NestJS service with Mongoose

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab, nestjs, pipeline

I am trying to configure the **gitlab-ci.yml** file for a simple backend NestJS project in a **Gitlab** Continuos Integration scope, that project has services to persist with a MongoDB database.

I have a angular client too and previously I installed that client correctly at Gitlab and I can access it through the public GitLab site.

[image]

I used this **gitlab-ci.yml** file for the backend project.

```html
image: node:14.15.0

stages:
  - install
  - test
  - build
  - deploy

install:
  stage: install
  script: 
- npm install
  artifacts:
expire_in: 1h
paths:
  - node_modules/
  cache:
paths:
  - node_modules/

tests:
  stage: test
  dependencies:
- install
  script:
- npm run test:ci
  coverage: '/Statements.*?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)%/'

build:
  stage: build
  variables:
BUILD_CONFIG: 'production'
  dependencies:
- install
  script:
- npm run build
  artifacts:
expire_in: 1h
paths:
  - dist/
  only:
- master

pages:
  stage: deploy
  dependencies:
- build
  script:
- npm i -g @nestjs/cli
- npm install
- nest start
  artifacts:
paths:
  - public/
  environment:
name: production
  only:
- master
```

This file executes the stages **"install, test and build"** successfully, but at the deploy stage it fails, see image.

[image]

As you can see after start it tries to connect to the MongoDB database and fails.

In the **deploy stage** I install the **NestJs** module and start it, but I think this is not correct the proper way is to use Docker images for both NestJs and MongoDB, but really I dont know exactly how to do that at GitLab side.

So I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite late to answer but you should have a Dockerfile in which u tell the container how to start, and start it in gitlab-ci.yml with docker run or with docker compose

**Dokerfile**

```yaml
FROM node:lts 
WORKDIR /home/src/app  

# Set to dev environment
ENV NODE_ENV development

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
CMD ["node", "dist/main"]
```

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```yaml
deploy_devel:
  stage: deploy
  ...
  script:
    - docker run ...
```